# Setting X and Y coordinates on a different device

Tags: android, coordinates

I have relative view inside one image having `matchparent` height and width, want to set X and Y coordinates in different devices. with that same view. 
As I have tried like,

**1) to getting Width and height :**

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y;
```

**2) then get X and Y coordinates :**

```
touchX = event.getX();
touchY = event.getY();
```

**3) I have applied some scenarios:
 - to save percentage in DB**

```
 perX = touchX/screenWidth;
 perY = touchY/screenHeight;
```

**and display that x and y to other device :**

```
newTouchX = perX*newDeviceWidth;
newTouchY = perY*newDeviceHeight;
```

but, not getting any result.
Looking forward to hear from you.
Thanks

Comment: `"with that same view."` what is it? an `ImageView`?

Comment: Use the screen density. `densityDpi * dp` should give a generic value, where `densityDpi` comes from `display`, and `dp` is the X or Y value.

Comment: @pskink, yes it is an Imageview.